# How to prove that any preference relation on (countable) X has a utility representation with a range (0,1)?

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, economics

**Theorem:** If $X$ is countable, then any preference on $X$ has a utility representation with a range $(0,1)$.

The stated proof in Rubinstein's lecture notes:

**Proof:** Let $\{x_n\}$ be an enumeration of all elements in $X$. We will construct the utility function inductively. Set $U(x_1) =1/2$. Assume that you have completed the definition of the values $U(x_1), . . ., U(x_{n-1})$ so that $x_k \succeq x_l$ iff $U(x_k) \geq U(x_l)$. If $x_n$ is indifferent to $x_k$ for some $k<n$, then assign $U(x_n)=U(x_k)$. If not, choose $U(x_n)$ to be between the two nonempty sets $\{U(x_k) | x_k \prec x_n \} \cup \{0\}$ and $\{U(x_k) | x_n \prec x_k \} \cup \{1\}$. This is possible since by transitivity all numbers in the first set are below all numbers in the second set. Thus, for any $k<n$ we have $x_n \succeq x_k$ iff $U(x_n) \geq U(x_k)$ and the function $U$ extended to $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ represents the preferences on those elements.
To complete the proof that $U$ represents $\succeq$, take any two elements, $x$ and $y\in X$. For some $k$ and $l$ we have $x=x_k$ and $y=y_l$. The above applied to $n=\max\{k,l\}$ yields $x_k \succeq x_l$ iff $U(x_k) \geq U(x_l)$.

I highlighted below the step in the proof I couldn't figure out. I tried to draw a number line or break the parts of the statement, yet couldn't understand.

> If not, choose $U(x_n)$ to be between the two nonempty sets $\{U(x_k)
> > | x_k \prec x_n \} \cup \{0\}$ and $\{U(x_k) | x_n \prec x_k \} \cup
> > \{1\}$. This is possible since by transitivity all numbers in the
> first set are below all numbers in the second set.

Furthermore, why have we done this step? Is it necessary to complete the proof?

> Set $U(x_1) =1/2$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If not, choose $U(x_n)$ to be between the two nonempty sets $\{U(x_k)
> > | x_k \prec x_n \} \cup \{0\}$ and $\{U(x_k) | x_n \prec x_k \} \cup
> > \{1\}$. This is possible since by transitivity all numbers in the
> first set are below all numbers in the second set.

Since $x_k$ is not indifferent to any of $x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$, we need to pick a value for $U(x_n)$ so that for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$:

- $U(x_n)>x_k$  when $x_n\succ x_k$
- $U(x_n)<x_k$  when $x_n\prec x_k$

The quoted text is just saying we can do this because the values of $U(x_k)$ for elements $x_k$ such that $x_k\prec x_n$ are all strictly less than the values  of $U(x_j)$ for elements $x_j$ such that $x_j\succ x_n$. This is because transitivity means that if $x_j\succ x_n$ and $x_n\succ x_k$ then $x_j\succ x_k$ and we know that $U(x_j)>U(x_k)$ (as we have already completed the definition of $U$ for those elements of $X$ and it cannot be that $U(x_j)=U(x_k)$ because then it would have to be that $x_j$ and $x_k$ are indifferent.)

> Set $U(x_1)=1/2$

This just deals with the base case of the inductive proof (when $n=1$). If we set $U(x_1)=1/2$, then clearly we have satisfied the requirement that  $U(x_1)\geq U(x_1)$ iff $x_1\succeq x_1$. (We don't have to choose $1/2$, we could set $U(x_1)$ to any number in $(0,1)$.)